# matlab - find indices of elements in x

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a matrix `x` of size Nx2 (contains (x,y) coordinates) and a matrix `c` of size Px1 (P<=N) that contains certain x-coordinates which I'm interested in. For example:

```
x = [10 3; 21 9; 98 54; 4 30; 37 12];
c = [4 98];
```

I want to get the coordinates of the elements in `c` (in the above case `[4 3]`). How can I do this? I've only found a way when `c` is a 1x1 matrix (i.e. a scalar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ismember` can be used for testing membership of multiple values. You can slice the N-by-2 matrix to search only x-coordinates.

```
coords = [1 2; 3 4; 5 6; 7 8];
c = [3 7 99];
[v i] = ismember(c, coords(:, 1));
i = 
  [2 4 0]
```

`i` should contain the indices where values in `c` appear as the x-coordinate in `coords`, or a 0 if the element is not found.
If you have a recent version of Matlab, you can replace `v` with `~`.

Comment: The problem with this one is that it doesn't return the indices in the same order they appear in x.

Comment: it will return them in the order of `c`. You can get them in the order of x using `i = sort(i)`.